# Sound sensor only detect peaks

Tags: arduino-nano, sound

I'm using this [SparkFun Sound Sensor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12642) in my project for a simple ambient sound meter.

I'm just trying to monitor the raw analog envelope output for the moment.

My problem is that the output only changes with peak sounds, like a clap in my hands for example. But when the ambient sound is louder, people talking or loud music, the output doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to increase the gain, see inside the document

[Sound dectector hookup guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sound-detector-hookup-guide?_ga=2.163503161.463025551.1581195689-620897650.1579562509)

The following fragment:

[image: Fragment]

Also take into account it needs between 3.5 and 5.5 V, while 5 V is ideal (see Quick start at the beginning of the same document.

Comment: I thought this is only for the sound detection (gate output) but I'll give it a try, thank you for the insight!

Comment: I never used this component, but I guess it will improve the sound sensivity, which is what should be increased if you get too less gain.

Comment: I've tried it and it changed nothing :(

Comment: Sorry to hear … a poor man solution would be to use an opamp/amplifier before the input of this sound detector.

Comment: Maybe, it's above my knowledge at the moment.
Thank you for you replies though :)